# Classes involved with the Eclipse main menubar

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, aop, trace

I'm using Equinox Weaving to monitor some Eclipse plugins, in particular those related with the UI. I've written several advices that trace some information when a certain UI element is used by a user (e.g. click on Run button).
The thing is that I haven't been able to trace the classes involved with the main menubar (File, Edit, Source, ....), is there a way to know which "method/class" is executed when a menu option is clicked by a user.

I've read some documentation, but I didn't find useful information that explained the classes involved in these types of operations.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you mean the class which is executed to implement a particular menu item look at [Eclipse plug-in/Menu Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)

Comment: I've tried to use the Eclipse plug-in/Menu Spy for this issue and is not possible for the main level of the menu, if you try to click on the main level using alt+shift+f2 you'll see that it will not let you select that level.